# PWMing the output of a constant current driver

Tags: mosfet, pwm, led-driver, constant-current

I have a set of LED panels that come with AC-DC constant current drivers. Is it acceptable to use a MOSFET to PWM the LED (MOSFET goes between the driver and the LED)?

Also the microcontroller that will be producing the PWM will use a different AC-DC power supply. Is it OK to common the ground rails from the LED driver and the microcontroller PSU, or is it advisable to use an optocoupler?

Comment: Your apology is accepted.

Comment: PWMing the output of a CC LED driver may not be a good idea. Do the drivers not have any kind of control input?

Comment: Do your AC-DC CC drivers have a shutdown or enable input? That will work much better.

Comment: The driver has no control inputs. Only AC in, DC out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It really depends on how the constant current driver has been designed.

- If you place the MOSFET in series with the LED, the constant current driver will most likely raise its output voltage until it hits its voltage limit. If the driver has no overvoltage protection (very unlikely) it will fry itself. Every time the transistor turns back on the LED will be exposed to momentary overvoltage as the driver feedback readjusts itself, which might damage the LED in some cases.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flIrPH.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

- If you place the MOSFET in parallel with the LED the constant current driver will most likely lower its output voltage close to zero in order to maintain the current at the setpoint. Again, some drivers might behave unpredictably if they are designed with a minimum output voltage in mind. 
  The LED however will not be exposed to overvoltage in this case, as the driver will have to ramp the voltage up, not down.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHmpnj.png)</sup>

In any case the driver will most likely not appreciate the wildly fluctuating load, the best option would be to just control the setpoint of the driver.